# Epistemic Uncertainty for branch-and-bound methods

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I want to ask some leads on how to quantify or propagate an epistemic type of uncertainty (e.g. statistical uncertainty) when performing a branch-and-bound (sort of fault tree analysis). The literature that I am currently looking at right now are the Markov Chain Monte Carlo Methods but I can not see any specific example that was applied into 'fault tree analysis'.

Can anyone give me some lead on this topic (videos, websites, whatever).